# Securing Video in android

Tags: android, security, sqlite, video

Im presently working on an android application which will allow the user to download video and audio content from a server and play them on the phone of the end user.

What I'm trying to do is to secure the audio and video. The files should not be accessible to other applications and the user must not be able to take them off the device and use them.

This is a shot in the dark but can i do this by storing the videos in theSQLLite database as blobs.
And also is it possible to play the videos in android if they are stored as blobs.

Comment: Hi avinash I am having similar problem!! did u have any answer for this now!!

Comment: Im sorry im replying so late, But what we ended up doing is getting the byte array for the video and performing a bitwise not on every byte. This gave us a basic level of security and made is difficult for the anyone to play it

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use blobs, they are only performant if the binary-files are 256KB or less.

I guess the only way to make the videos secure so the user can't use them is to stream them down from you'r server and deleting the buffer when the Application closes.

On a rootet Device, you have access to every directory, so you can't save the videos on the SDcard or the Phone-Memory.

Comment: See the problem is that when a video is downloaded, it should be saved in the users phone. Is there any way i can atleast encrpyt the video?